# How to add a class to a Livewire component root tag?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Laravel Livewire, I have this simple `hello` component:

```html
<div>
    Hello world
</div>
```

I would like to add a `foobar` class to the root div of this component when I use it.

I want the final rendered html to be:

```html
<div class="foobar">
    Hello world
</div>
```

How can I add this class without editing the component itself?

I tried to call this component by doing `<livewire:hello class="foobar" />` and everything works fine... except the class is not there. In fact, it's not limited to `class`, all attributes disappear.

The rendered html always looks like this:

```html
<div wire:id="jYDWRZST6NCW11Qty9gp">
    Hello world
</div>
```

Is there something else I should do in order to give this component a class when I use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike blade components, Livewire doesn't support that. You need to add the class inside the component's blade.

```xml
<div class="footer">
    Hello world
</div>
```

```xml
<livewire:hello />
```

Alternatively you would need to manually define an attribute inside the component's Class.

```php
class Hello extends Component
{
    public $classes
}
```

```xml
<div class="{{ $classes }}">
    Hello world
</div>
```

```xml
<livewire:hello classes="footer" />
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some kind of "attributes inheritance", like Blade / Vue components. I did it by declaring a public property inside the component class, but that felt hacky for this purpose. Furthermore, ChatGPT kept telling me there was a `wire:class` attribute that no one seemed to talk about except him... pretty confusing. Anyway, thank you :)